# Assign number sequentially using RANK() when a condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (`dbo.[mytable]`) like below:

```
  Plnt     StageCode      MatCode    Flag
   P1         3001          3001      1
   P1         3001          CH03      0
   P1         3001          200FG     0
   P2         3001          3001      1
   P2         3001          GG45      0
   P2         3001          4501      0
   P3         CH03          2001      0
   P3         CH03          4002      0
   P3         CH03          CH03      1
```

I want another column in the above table where numbers will be assigned sequentially for a `Plnt` and `StageCode` combination where condition flag<>1 is met. Also another column where `StageCode` would be plotted when flag=1 till the next occurance of flag=1.
**Below is the desired output:**

```
  Plnt     StageCode      MatCode    Flag   Stage    SKU
   P1         3001          3001      1     Final    3001
   P1         3001          CH03      0       1      3001
   P1         3001          200FG     0       2      3001
   P2         3001          3001      1     Final    3001
   P2         3001          GG45      0       1      3001
   P2         3001          4501      0       2      3001
   P3         CH03          CH03      1     Final    CH03
   P3         CH03          4002      0       1      CH03
   P3         CH03          2001      0       2      CH03
```

I have tried the below approach:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM (
    SELECT A.Plnt, A.StageCode, A.MatCode
        , CASE WHEN A.Flag = 1 THEN 'Final' 
        ELSE CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(A.Plnt, A.StageCode) ORDER BY CONCAT(A.Plnt, A.MatCode) DESC) AS CHAR(2))
        END AS Stage
        , ISNULL(CASE WHEN A.Flag = 1 THEN A.StageCode END, A.StageCode) AS SKU
    FROM dbo.[myTable] A
) B;
```

The above approach is not working as I am getting `Stage` in some cases 1 right after `Final` sometimes 2. Secondly, the order is getting reset based on `CONCAT(Plnt,StageCode)` basis which I do not want.

Any clue? What I am missing here?

SQL Fiddle Link : [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c02f6/4)

Comment: point taken @DaleK. can you please provide any fiddle link?

Comment: @DaleK: Added the SQL Fiddle link.

Comment: @DaleK: It should be `CONCAT(Plnt,StageCode)`

Comment: Because in cases where flag<>1 it will populate NULL

Comment: @DaleK: Your suggestions were useful. However, few additional adjustments need to be done and I would do that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of issues, but the fundamental one is the lack of a unique ordering column within your partition because `CONCAT(A.Plnt, A.StageCode)` is the definition of the partition, but you don't provide any column to order by inside this partition. When an ordering column is added it works as you expect. Other issues:

1. Add an ordering column
2. You don't need a sub-query
3. Don't use `CONCAT(A.Plnt, A.StageCode)` because you prevent the use of indexes, instead use `A.Plnt, A.StageCode`
4. Your sample data shows that your `SKU` column is identical to your `StageCode` column, so not sure what the issue is there.
5. You don't need `DENSE_RANK`, a simple `ROW_NUMBER` will suffice.
6. Your fiddle shows a single P1 row, which you don't explain how this should look in the results.

```
SELECT A.Plnt, A.StageCode, A.MatCode
    , CASE WHEN A.Flag = 1 THEN 'Final' 
    ELSE CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Plnt, A.StageCode ORDER BY A.Plnt, A.MatCode, A.OrderByColumn) - 1 AS CHAR(2))
    END AS Stage
    , A.StageCode AS SKU
FROM dbo.[myTable] A
ORDER BY A.Plnt, A.MatCode, A.OrderByColumn;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8O0dpuTg) showing it working with an ordering column.